# How to convert List<String[]> to List<Object> using modelmapper or stream().map()?

Tags: java, java-stream, lombok, modelmapper

I have the following Data as list of String[] in java, is it possible to convert using the stream().map() ? This is an example of the List.

```
Data's type is List<String[]> data which contains the following structure:
["a","b","c","d"],
["e","f","g","e"],
["e","f","g","e"]
```

I was trying to map my values with the modelMapper and without modelMapper and the data is empty:

```
List<Custom> mapInfo = new ArrayList<CustomData>();
mapInfo=data.stream().map(objectModel -> modelMapper.map(objectModel, CustomData.class)).collector(Collectors.toList());
```

However when i try to use the data, the object structure is empty on every object of the array:

```
 @Getter
 @Setter
 @Builder
 @NoArgsConstructor
 @AllArgsConstructor
 public class CustomData(){
   @Builder.Default
   private String valueA="";
   @Builder.Default
   private String valueB="";
   @Builder.Default
   private String valueC="";
   @Builder.Default
   private String valueD="";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have all arguments constructor for class `CustomData` you can do something like this

```
    data.stream()
        .map(row -> new CustomData(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: is there any alternative without using the index? since if there is a new parameter added to the class, i need to modify the rows for the constructor and the class itself.(if  there is not possible i'll mark this as the answer)

Comment: You can for example create something like this inside `CustomData` class
```public static CustomData from(String[] input) {
    return new CustomData(input[0], input[1], input[2], input[3]);
  }
``` and have this logic encapsulated inside this class and use it inside stream.